# Insertar con tres tablas relacionadas en ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

necesito ayuda para insertar datos en tres tablas relacionadas(dos tablas y una que las relaciona), esta es la estructura:

```
Tabla alumnos
(
   id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   nombre varchar(60),
   edad int
)
Tabla cursos 
(
   id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   descripcion varchar(60),
   costo money
)
Tabla inscripcion(esta es la de relación)
(
   id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   id_alumno int references alumnos(id),
   id_curso int references cursos(id),
   fecha_inscripcion date
)
```

La cosa es que no encuentro la forma de insertar en Mvc y que quede todo organizado(osea, los alumnos con su respectivo curso(o cursos)) y su fecha de inscripción. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estas hablando de bbdd o de asp.net?

Comment: Tengo las tres tablas relacionadas en sql y las he mapeado con entity framework, pero quiero insertar registros de las 3 tablas

Comment: Sin el código que tienes hecho no puedo ver que te puede estar fallando, pulsa [edit] para añadirlo

Comment: **En el modelo de datos tengo el siguiente ViewModel:**  
    public class MiViewModel
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public double? Costo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? fechaRegistro { get; set; }
    }

Comment: **este es el codigo del controlador:**  
        [HttpGet]  
        public ActionResult Agregar()  
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Agregar(miViewModel model)  
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.alumnos.Add(model);  
                db.SaveChanges();  
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: **me sale este error:**
   Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from   
   'WebApplication4.ViewModels.miViewModel' to  'WebApplication4.Models.alumnos'

Comment: creo que debes publicar el controlador en la pregunta, lo otro es que debes definir si vas a inscribir un alumno en un curso como es la relación, consulta esta pagina para que te guies sobre las realciones que debes tener https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Es bastante importante que pulses en [edit] y añadas en la pregunta tanto el código del ViewModel como el error que te está lanzando. Los comentarios son superfluos en el sitio y pueden eliminarse en cualquier momento

Answer (score 0):

Tu error:

> **Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WebApplication4.ViewModels.miViewModel' to 'WebApplication4.Models.alumnos'**

Significa que tienes un modelo miViewModel y lo quieres transformar en alumnos, que en la información que dispongo no existe, tan solo en base de datos. Para ello puedes generar un conversor de miViewModel a alumno de la siguiente manera:

```
public alumno ToVm(miViewModel modelo)
{
    return new alumno 
    {
        Nombre = modelo.Nombre,
        Edad = modelo.Edad,
        Descripcion = modelo.Descripcion,
        Costo = modelo.Costo,
        fechaRegistro = modelo.fechaRegistro
    };
}
```

y crear el ViewModel alumno:

```
public class alumno 
{ 
    public string Nombre { get; set; } 
    public int Edad { get; set; } 
    public string Descripcion { get; set; } 
    public double? Costo { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? fechaRegistro { get; set; } 
}
```

Entonces al llamar a la función ToVm convertirá tu modelo miViewModel a alumno.